# Trigger Ember action from javascript console

Tags: ember.js, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I don't know much about Ember but I'm trying to manipulate an Ember web app. There's an element in the DOM that has this property "data-ember-action-981="981"" and I'd like to trigger the function linked to it in order to access its output.

Any ideas on how to do it ?
Thanks

Comment: an ember action has, by design, no output. can you clarify? An action is doing something, not returning data. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can simulate a click on it through JavaScript.

```
document.querySelector('[data-ember-action-981]').click();
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to retrieve the data directly in javascript. Doing this triggers the function and that sends the data to my clipboard...

Comment: Please edit your question. You asked how to trigger the function.